# Cannot set the file modified date when inserting file to Google Drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive API Java client library to insert files to Google Drive. Any file that is uploaded to Drive takes on the modified time of when it is uploaded, not the original file modified time. I've used the `setModifiedDate` of `File` object to set the date.

On seeing the documentation at [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), I see the following text -

> Last time this file was modified by anyone (formatted RFC 3339
>   timestamp). This is only mutable on update when the setModifiedDate
>   parameter is set.

However, I cannot find the parameter `setModifiedDate` in the documentation, and neither the Java library has the method `setSetModifiedDate(Boolean arg)` in the class `com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.Insert` (On the contrary, the update class `com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.Update` contains the `setSetModifiedDate(Boolean arg)` method which works perfectly).

Comment: Hey jai, I'm filing a feature request internally for this. Indeed it seems this was only enabled for Update operations but I see how this is useful for Insert operations.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me to keep the modified date & time of a file before I upload it to Drive.

```
long modifiedDateTime = new java.io.File("/path/to/file").lastModified();
Time t = new Time();
t.set(modifiedDateTime);
t.switchTimezone(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
String modifiedDateAsRfc3339 = t.format3339(false);

// create the file to upload here
com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new File();
body.setTitle("/path/to/file");
body.setMimeType("mimetype");
// here is where you set the modified date to match the file's modified date
body.setModifiedDate(com.google.api.client.util.DateTime.parseRfc3339(modifiedDateAsRfc3339));


InputStreamContent mediaContent;
......
```